# In the Erlang shell, how can I automatically read all my record definition headers

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

This started off as the question:

Almost every time when I use the Erlang shell, I'd like to run some command on shell startup, e.g. something like

```
rr("*.hrl").
```

Or similar.  Currently I have to type it every time I start a Erlang shell and I'm getting tired of it and forget it all the time.

**But** this was actually the wrong question! For what I actually wanted to do is read my record definition headers in every shell job.  Not use for other of the shell built-in commands to run on startup.  So I changed the question header to show the question how it should have asked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

While trying the solution with `.erlang` I stumbled upon a solution for the specific `rr/1` usage:

From the man-page of shell:

> There  is  some  support for reading and printing records in the shell.
> During compilation record expressions are translated to  tuple  expres-
> sions. In runtime it is not known whether a tuple actually represents a
> record. Nor are the record definitions used by  compiler  available  at
> runtime.  So  in  order  to  read the record syntax and print tuples as
> records when possible, record definitions have to be maintained by  the
> shell  itself.  The  shell  commands for reading, defining, forgetting,
> listing, and printing records are described below. Note that  each  job
> has  its  own  set  of record definitions. To facilitate matters record
> definitions in the modules shell_default and user_default  (if  loaded)
> are read each time a new job is started. For instance, adding the line
>
> ```
>   -include_lib("kernel/include/file.hrl").
> ```
>
> to  user_default makes the definition of file_info readily available in
> the shell.

For clarification I add some example:

File `foo.hrl`:

```
-record(foo, {bar, baz=5}).
```

File: `user_default.erl`:

```
-module(user_default).
-compile(export_all).

-include("foo.hrl").  % include all relevant record definition headers here

 %% more stuff probably ...
```

Lets try out in the shell:

```
$ erl
Erlang R13B04 (erts-5.7.5) [source] [smp:2:2] [rq:2] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.7.5  (abort with ^G)
1> #foo{}.
#foo{bar = undefined,baz = 5}
```

→ the shell knows about the record from `foo.hrl`

Answer (score 3):

The file `.erlang` is evaluated when the shell is started, but it is **NOT** evaluated in the context of the shell. This means that it can only contain general expressions which are evaluated and not shell commands. Unfortunately `rr()` is a shell command (it initialises local shell data to recognise records) so it can not be used in the `.erlang` file.

While the user defined module `user_default`, which must be preloaded, can include files which contain record definitions using `-include` or `-include_lib`, these record definitions will then only be available to functions defined within `user_default`. `user_default` is normal compiled module and exported functions in it are called as any other functions so the record definitions will not be visible within the shell. `user_default` allows the user to define more complex functions which can be called from within the shell as shell commands.

EDIT:

I was partially wrong here. While I was correct about how `.erlang` is evaluated and how the functions in `user_default` are called I missed how `user_default.erl` is scanned at shell startup for record definitions which are then available within the shell. Thanks @Peer Stritzinger for pointing this out.

Comment: Are you sure? The text from the manpage seems to say otherwise.  To check I set up a small test case (see http://ideone.com/4Gau5)  As it looks it seems to work.  Am I missing something?

Comment: No, you haven't missed anything. I was checking the code and only saw the using of functions in `shell_default` and `user_default` and missed the scanning done of them at shell startup. Mea culpa.

Answer (score 0):

Place it in file called `.erlang` in your home directory (see paragraph 1.7.1 in http://www.erlang.org/documentation/doc-5.2/doc/getting_started/getting_started.html).

Comment: For the example of rr() i have difficulty to make this work.  For one if I only put the line as stated above in .erlang it doesn't find rr/1 and I don't know what module rr/1 is defined in.  On the other hand I'm not sure this will be available in all shell jobs.

Comment: @Peer Stritzinger: `rr()` is not defined as a function; you can find it in `stdlib/shell.erl` as a clause of the `local_func/7` function.

Comment: @Zed: yes that was my problem and I was looking for a way to auto call it anyway.  Fund the workaround in my self-answer and as I can't think of any other of the shell built-in pseudo-functions needed at startup the problem is solved for me by the workaround.

Comment: Therfore changed the question to show what I should have asked to make this useful for others ...